# how to use Declaration Merging from npm package

Tags: typescript

i make simple test for "Declaration Merging"

it 's simple 
add hello method to rxjs.Ovservable

```
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function hello <T>(this: Observable<T> ): Observable<T> {
    console.log('hello');
    return this;
}

Observable.prototype.hello = hello;

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    interface Observable<T> {
        hello: typeof hello;
    }
}

describe('main test', () => {
    it('test 01', () => {
        Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .hello()
            .map(x => x)
            .subscribe(x => (console.log(x)));
    });
});
```

it's works (use test framework(`jest`) )

so, i try to make npm package

https://github.com/m0a/hello-observable

but, error occured.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs';
import 'hello-observable'; // my local npm package

describe('main test', () => {
    it('test 01', () => {
        Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .hello() // error is here
            .map(x => x)
            .subscribe(x => (console.log(x)));
    });
});


// error message: 'Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.'
```

please help.

Comment: Where are you running this test from? Within the `hello-observable` directory?

Comment: test code is other project
here. 
https://github.com/m0a/declaration-merging

please run `yarn test` or `npm test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package.json of your package should point to the file with the types in it, e.g.:

```
"typings": "src/index.ts",
```

(But it is better to point to index.d.ts. See below.)

A few other things. 1. You should compile the ts file to a js file and package.json should point to that too. E.g.:

```
"main": "dist/output-file.js",
```

2. Have the compiler output an index.d.ts file and point to that from package.json. E.g. if you use tsc then add the --declaration option to the command-line.

   ```
   "typings": "index.d.ts",
   ```
3. Your 'declaration-merging' project needs to reference the 'hello-observable' project. E.g. run:

   ```
   npm install --save https://github.com/m0a/hello-observable
   ```
4. You should remove the 'npm link hello-observable' from package.json. If you want to use your local copy of hello-observable then run 'npm link' from the hello-observable directory and 'npm link hello-observable' from the declaration-merging directory. These commands just need to be run once and shouldn't be committed.
5. Use import 'hello-observable", not import './hello-observable'.

Comment: but this answer occured  a new question.

almost library's package.json typings field pointed at `index.d.ts`
but this answer use  `"typings": "src/index.ts"`  now.
why?

Comment: Ideally you should have the compiler output the index.d.ts file and have the package.json point to that. This is cleaner since index.d.ts won't be polluted by non-type stuff, e.g. your tests. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: So we can say that `import './hello-observable'` triggers a declaration merging right? Is this trick documented in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs)?